# SMART data no longer available for my external HDD in disks utility

Tags: permissions, external-hdd

I no longer can check my external HDD status by using SMART data and self-tests.

Using disks the option that was available before is just disabled as in the following screenshot:
[image]

*I guess it's related to some permissions, but I don't know what to do.*

Comment: [pic](http://i.imgur.com/It5EV2C.png)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) 1/ you didn't accidentally click on a USB drive, did you? (Don't laugh: happened to me!) 2/ what happens if you install `smartmontools` and do a `smartctl --scan`? 3/ does `gksudo gnome-disks` change anything?

Comment: @fappy Sorry, I don't get the first one. the output of `smartctl --scan is` `/dev/sda -d scsi # /dev/sda, SCSI device
/dev/sdb -d sat # /dev/sdb [USB Cypress], ATA device
`. and using gksudo does not affect any thing ...

Comment: Which of the three disks did you try in the screen shot? (and was giving SMART stuff before?)

Comment: it's `sdb`. they are just two: sda is internal and sdb is external..

Comment: and on `sda` it still works?

Comment: yup, still works on `sda`. but for the other one i've tried a command `sudo smartctl --all /dev/sdb -d sat,12 -T permissive
` and it told me what it means that your hdd is dying, save your data! so, ASAP i'll buy a new one. thank you @fappy.

Comment: Please, please, please **make a back-up now!**.  Borrow, bribe, buy, do whatever it takes to get your hands on a HDD so you can back-up your data. BTW, you've been calling me Fa**pp**y for so long now that I've started assimilating myself with that, but it's Fa**bb**y!  ;-)

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry for changing your name :D, it was a mistake. I already made a back-up, thank you so much Mr. @Fabby :)

Comment: Don't worry, it looked funny anyway.  And how would you know I'm a "Mr."?  If you look more closely to my image, you will see I'm an Alien and have no sex at all!  :D  ;-)  And please don't thank me: just click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of my answer, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)  and if you *really* like it, press the "up-arrow" above it as well!

Answer (score 3):

It's never good news if a hard-disk suddenly starts not reporting on SMART data.

Therefore, please check if your drive have SMART capabilities:

```
sudo hdparm -I /dev/XdY
```

(where X=`h` or `s` and Y=`a`, `b`, `c`, ... depending on your hardware) and enable it:

```
sudo smartctl --smart=on /dev/sdb
```

and install the command-line version of the SMART monitoring:

```
apt-get install smartmontools
```

Then perform the command:

```
smartctl --scan
```

which should give you the drives you have on the system.  Then perform a more in-depth scan on the troubled drive by typing:

```
smartctl --all /dev/XdY
```

If the test above doesn't give any conclusive results, run an even more in-depth testing by:

```
smartctl --all /dev/XdY --test=short
```

For more information: `man smartctl`

**In your case, with serious errors, [please make a back-up first](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) and then go out and buy a new drive!**

Comment: And as you're a reputation 6 user: Don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Comment: You can always check if your drive have SMART capabilities: `sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb` and enable it: `sudo smartctl --smart=on /dev/sdb` or `sudo smartctl -s on /dev/sdb` .

Comment: @PabloBianchi: Your comment incorporated into the answer.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

You can list all drives and check in one line command.

```
for i in {a..z}; do printf "\n/dev/sd$i\n"; smartctl --all /dev/sd$i | grep -i '$family\|model\|capacity\|Serial Number\|reallocated_Sector\|Uncorrectable\|Start_Stop_Count\|Power_On_Hours\|Power_Cycle_Count\|Command_Timeout\|High_Fly_Writes\|Airflow_Temperature\|Temperature_Celsius\|Load_Cycle_Count\|Current_Pending_Sector\|Retract_Count\|Reported_Uncorrect'; done
```